# JOptionPane Input to int

Tags: java, swing, integer, user-input, joptionpane

I am trying to make a JOptionPane get an input and assign it to an int but I am getting some problems with the variable types.

I am trying something like this:

```
Int ans = (Integer) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Text",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            null,
            "[sample text to help input]");
```

But I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot
be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Which sounds logical yet, I cannot think of another way to make this happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use:

```
int ans = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
        "Text",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        null,
        "[sample text to help input]"));
```

You cannot cast a `String` to an `int`, but you can convert it using `Integer.parseInt(string)`.

Comment: Hmm... it seems I need to also add
   int ans = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
        "Text",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        null,
        "[sample text to help input]").toString());

Comment: @devil If you use the correct form of `showinputdialog` you won't need to do that.  But, you are correct in some cases.

Comment: I see I see. If I may ask one more thing, is there a way, using a loop maybe, to check if the input given actually is an integer or not? Sth like: ... do { ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...) } until ans = integer  ?

Answer (score 5):

This because the input that the user inserts into the `JOptionPane` is a `String` and it is stored and returned as a `String`.

Java cannot convert between strings and number by itself, you have to use specific functions, just use:

```
int ans = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class JOptionSample { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First integer");

      String name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second integer");

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first inputted is 89 and the second 
    integers inputted is 45" );

    int number =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "89+45 = "));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Question Message", "Title",
   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to continue? ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choice is "+option);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The sum of the two integers is : 134 ");
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Integer.parseInt throws an NumberFormatException if the passed string doesn't contain a parsable string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// sample code for addition using JOptionPane

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Addition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input <First Integer>");

        String secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input <Second Integer>");

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum is" + sum, "Sum of two Integers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String String_firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input  Semisecond");
int Int_firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
```

Now your `Int_firstnumber` contains integer value of `String_fristNumber`.

hope it helped