# How to make a perfect integer dialog on Java?

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I want to make a perfect integer dialog on Java, where you cannot type letters, only numbers

Here is my code:

```
public class PMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the number for 'A'");
        int A = Integer.parseInt(a.trim());
        String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the number for 'B'");
        int B = Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JOptionPane Input to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120922/joptionpane-input-to-int)

Comment: Doesn't sound too perfect to me. I'd expect the *perfect* dialog to support scientific notation like `1e6` for a million. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own Dialog for that (not JOptionPane) and use JFormattedTextField and MaskFormatter. You can find an Example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).